# How to use assert within async functions? (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, async-await, assert

I have a block like below, which is a function using `async`
If I add an assert statement in there, it will stop the code executing at that line, but no error is thrown. It just dies silently :(

```
async function testMongo() {
  let db = await dbConnect();

  await db.collection("stories").remove({});
  let c = await count("stories", {} );
  assert.strictEqual(c, 999);   // should fail
  console.log("moving on...");  /// will never get reached.

}
```

Is there some reason that the assertion maybe gets swallowed up?
I've had problems like these before with errors inside event emitters, and it seems the immediate return of the async function is some type of event emitter/Promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

console.log() call can be skipped is if async db.connection() or count() will reject their promises. It this case your should try wrapping those calls in try/catch:

```
try
{
    await db.collection("stories").remove({});
}
catch(e)
{
    //...    
}
```

Or catch error using promise:

```
await db.collection("stories").remove({}).catch((e) => {//...});
```

[EDIT]

The generic wrapper that will execute async function and continue even on rejection can look something like this:

```
async function Do<T>(func: ()=>Promise<T>)
{
    try
    {
        await func();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        console.log(e);  
    }
}
```

Comment: i wonder if there's a way to push than into a generic wrapper for all `await`ed functions?